# How do I structure the db effectively to query historic data like "Who was the HOD of the department at a given point in time"?

Tags: database-design

First of all I am not sure if this question should be here or in stackoverflow. I decided to post it here because it is not a coding but architectural challenge.

#### Introduction

I have a data base design for an HRM system that I have come up with.

For simplicity, I am excluding lot of fields that is not relevant to this question.

```
Employees Table

id|emp_ref|machine_id|name                          |preferred_name|
--+-------+----------+------------------------------+--------------+
75|101    |M101      |Jonh Doe                      |Jonh          |
```

```
Employee Jobs Table

id |employee_id|designation_id|department_id|commence_from|end_date   |is_current|
---+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
105|         75|            24|            9|   2019-07-10| 2019-12-31|          |
405|         75|            28|            9|   2020-01-01|           |         1|
```

Here the employee got promoted on `2020-01-01` (A simple data to show what i meant)

If someone were to ask, what was John's designation on '2019-09-15', I can easily give him the answer (i.e. the designation with id `24`).

#### Now to the question

My current database design for storing the HOD is like so

```
Departments Table

id|name      |hod_id|
--+----------+------+
 9|Purchase  |    79|
```

I opt-in for this design, because at any given point there would only be one HOD. So I thought it is best to store it with the department itself.

However, Now I am posed with this question. who was the HOD of purchasing department on say: '2019-06-15`?

I can't query that because I am not storing it any were. How would I redesign the db so that I can accommodate the history also?

I have thought of storing it with the `jobs` table but then I would have to `update` all the employees in a department when a head of the department changes and i don't think its classy.

Or should I create a new table for storing that detail? and what if in the future they say we would need two HOD just in case one got sick, the other can take over.

How would I effectively design this? If anybody have gone through this and found a good design that can accommodate all those question, I would be very grateful if you can share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you would need to update the jobs table for all employees when the HOD changes? You just need to set the `end_date` for the previous HOD and the `commence_from` of the new HOD. Head of department is just one possible job some employee can have. The "one HOD per department at any time" constraint is probably not easy to express using the database, you may need to enforce it in the application.

Comment: By the way, don't maintain an `is_current` flag. It would potentially need to be updated each day, and the information is already encoded in the date interval.

Comment: If you want to bone up on it, search on the buzzphrase [Temporal Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database).

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I am aware of the maintainance. that needed to do on the is_current flag. but it is there just to ensure when I left join the table I only join 1 row. The combination of employee and is_current flag is unique for a job.

Comment: @MohamedMufeed, is there any possibility for `end_date is filled AND is_current = 1`? If not, then the presence of data in the `end_date` field serves the same purpose as the `is_current` field.

Comment: Ah I get it now. I just need to change the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement it as follows:

- employees table
- roles table (an org-chart mapping)
- and a roles assignment journal that tracks all the organisation changes (the key point here is to have a timestamp, employee id and a role id) which should allow you to query the history of each role or employee easily.

Comment: I think I will go with the org-chart mapping approch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The "head of department" is a designation like any other, so you should just store it in the `jobs` table as such.

The the question "who was the HOD of purchasing department on '2019-06-15'?" becomes a query for "who has the designation 'HOD' and the department 'purchasing' on '2019-06-15'?" and that question can be answered from your `jobs` table, with a join on the `departments` and `designations` tables to map the names to an id.

With a slightly more complicated query, you can even answer the question "who was the HOD of John's department at 2019-06-15?"

Comment: It is true. But here I am unable to enforce that. Because the designation could be anything and that goes on to his/her experience. So for `Purchase` department the head would be `Purchase Manager` and for `Sales` department the head would be `Sales Manager` and so on. My problem actually align more with [Florin's Answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/435882/354603) it is a generalised role.